# How to make a for loop read str and float values in a single list until the end of the list index?

Tags: python

This is my first post, and I'm fairly new to python and programming as a whole.  I apologize if I ask something stupid or format something incorrectly.

I'm currently programming a finch robot to read a list of user inputs which then runs sequentially based on the user input.  I've written the code leading up to the for loop, however I don't know what to do from here.

```
>userInputList = []

loop = False
while loop == False : 
    #Instructions for what to type
    print("W - Move Forward")
    print("S - Move Backward")
    print("A - Turn Left")
    print("D - Turn Right")
    print("X - Execute Commands")
    print("Q - Quit")
    userInput = str(input("Please enter a command for the Finch: "))
    if userInput.upper() in ["Q"] :
        print("Quitting")
        finch.close
        loop = True
    elif userInput.upper() in ["X"] :
        loop = True
        print("Executing")
    else :
        userInputList.append(userInput)
        userTime = float(input("Please enter the duration in seconds: "))
        userInputList.append(userTime)
        if userInput.upper() in ["W"] :
            print("Moving forward for " +str(userTime), "seconds")
        elif userInput.upper() in ["S"] :
            print("Moving backward for " +str(userTime), "seconds")
        elif userInput.upper() in ["A"] :
            print("Turning left for " +str(userTime), "seconds")
        elif userInput.upper() in ["D"] :
            print("Turning right for " +str(userTime), "seconds")
        else :
            print("")
```

The above is the code I have thus far which seems to be working correctly.  Below is the for loop code I'm confused about.  Would it work better if I accessed the pair of user inputs together? Or if I read the str values first and then the float values? I think I would do the latter by reading the list in increments of 2.

```
>for userInputList in range(0, len(userInputList), 2) :
if userInputList in ["W", "w"] :
    print("Working") #Used to determine if the loop is working correctly, will be deleted later on
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you want to keep your directions and times in a single flat list like that?  It might be easier to keep them separate.

Lets say you have a sequence of directions:

```
directions = ["W", "S", "W"]
```

And the corresponding sequence of times:

```
times = [0.5, 0.1, 0.2]
```

You can loop through them like this:

```
for direction, time in zip(directions, times):
    print(direction, time)
    #do something with them, move your robot, etc
```

If you don't want to keep them separate you could add them to the list in pairs like:

```
move_list.append((userInput, userTime))
```

And loop through them like this:

```
for direction, time in move_list:
    print(direction, time)
```

Does this answer your main question?

Just as a tip, you might consider also just making the result of your direction input uppercase as soon as you get it like this:

```
userInput = str(input("Please enter a command for the Finch: ")).upper()
```

That way you don't have to make it upper case every time you want to check its value.

Comment: Partly yes, it does. I just need to get the finch robot to read the values printed (direction, time) and move accordingly.  I think I would have to use an if statement with a few elif's for each input direction.